# How to run multiple sed commands on a list of files using find output piped through xargs

Tags: sed, find, xargs

This is what I tried:

```
find . -name *.sv | xargs sed -i -e '<command>' -e '<command>'
```

It does not work. Using the exact same command on each file still works.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Define 'does not work'.  What specifically _does_ it do?

Answer (score 7):

To force `xargs` to only execute `sed` with a single file at a time, use `-n 1` with `xargs`.  You should also pass the pathnames from `find` using `-print0` and get `xargs` to receive them with `-0` (if your `find` and `xargs` supports these nonstandard options), so that pathnames containing spaces etc. are handled correctly.  You probably also need to specify that you are looking for regular files (and not directories etc.) and you definitely need to quote that shell glob (or it may expand to any matching filename in the current directory):

```
find . -type f -name '*.sv' -print0 | xargs -0 -n 1 sed -i -e '<command>' -e '<command>'
```

Or, just use `find`:

```
find . -type f -name '*.sv' -exec sed -i -e '<command>' -e '<command>' {} ';'
```

Related:

- [Understanding the -exec option of `find`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389705)

---

A solution that is not using `find`, but instead uses the `**` globbing pattern (matches "recursively" down into subdirectories) available in `bash` after doing `shopt -s globstar`:

```bash
shopt -s globstar dotglob nullglob
for pathname in ./**/*.sv; do
    if [[ -f "$pathname" ]] && [[ ! -h "$pathname" ]]; then
        sed -i -e '<command> -e '<command>' "$pathname"
    fi
done
```

This loop loops over all files that have a filename suffix `.sv` and tests whether each matched name is a regular file (we have to test separately with `! -h` to make sure its not a symbolic link to a regular file) before applying the `sed` command.  The shell options enable the use of `**` (`globstar`), matching of hidden names (`dotglob`), and removes the patterns completely if it does not match (`nullglob`).

Or, with the `zsh` shell, which has `**` enabled by default, and can use a "glob qualifier" to do most of the "extra" work that `bash` has to do explicitly:

```sh
for pathname in ./**/.sv(.DN); do
    sed -i -e '<command> -e '<command>' "$pathname"
done
```

The glob qualifier `(.DN)` modifies the preceding globbing pattern so that it matches only regular files, matches hidden names, and expands to nothing if there is no match at all.

Comment: At least for GNU sed, doesn't `-i` imply `-s` (i.e. that sed will treat the files as separate, even if xargs doesn't)?

Comment: @steeldriver Possibly, I don't use GNU `sed` very often (and never with `-i`). The original command may still have issues with whitespace in file names though (and the other issues).

Comment: @Kusalananda I would also recommend combining both of the `-e` options on the `sed`. `-e` denotes a `sed` *script* will follow, not a `sed` command. `sed -e '<command1> ; <command2>' FILE` works just fine.

Comment: @Centimane If you want to get technical about it, `-e` denotes that the following argument is a `sed` expression or command. `-f` is used to read a script from a file. There is no benefit to combining the arguments of several `-e` into a single string, and in some cases, it's even impossible to do so.

Comment: @Kusalananda `-e` denotes a script as per the man page: "add the script to the commands to be executed". I don't think there are any cases where it's impossible, you just might have to escape some characters if using double-quotes instead of single. It is true though that the result is the same, but it's good to recognize that `-e` is for passing a *script* rather than a single *command*.

Comment: @Centimane Well, the POSIX spec uses the placeholder `script` but calls it "the editing commands", so I think we may both call ourselves correct on that point.  If you want to use the `sed` _command_ `a` or `i`, it's _nice looking_ to use `-e 'i\' -e 'text'` than to embed a newline in the single quoted string. Regardless of all of this, whether one or several `-e` is used (or none) is totally unimportant to this question.

Comment: Thanks for the solution @Kusalananda. I was wondering what would be the solution if I am not using find to get the filelist that is being fed to xargs. Since the -print0 and -0 options of find and xargs respectively seems to be made for each other.

Comment: @PrasadAddagarla See updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another method that worked for me:

```
find -name "*.fail" | xargs -L 1 sed -i -e 's/cse/ecs/g' -e 's/trex/dino/g'
```

Comment: This might work for you, but as a generic solution this would fail on files and directories that have newlines in their name.

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me
`grep -rl foo | xargs sed -i 's/foo/bar'`